# Process Builder And Flow Difference

Tags: process-builder

What is the Difference Between Process Builder And Flow .Any One Explain Me And Give  Any One Example With Sample Diagrams

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_action_flow.htm&language=en_US go through this Link it is Very Useful

Comment: I will Check And Let Me Known

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Process Builder is the Lightining Process it is advanced Model of Workflow Rule ,But Process Builder is Limited to some Restrictions and Constructions Diagram,But Flow Process is Not Limited Process,we Can Create a Record and update a Record and also Check the Conditon for all types of Records etc ,Flow Process can do in Visual Force Page itself

Comment: There is no need to start every word with a capital letter.

Comment: Also, what does this even mean? It's just one big run on.

Comment: This does not explain the differences clearly. Try and read your answer back assuming you do not know what it means and then see if you can understand it.

Answer (score 2):

When your questions are at such a basic level, you may find you are better served by working through Trailhead modules first. You should start with **[Process Automation - Figure Out Which Tool To Use](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/business_process_automation/process_whichtool)**, which has a good level of detail on your question at hand here:

> ### What to Do When a Record Has Certain Values
>
> This is the most common type of process that you can use Salesforce to automate, and three of our tools address this use case: Process Builder, Visual Workflow, and Workflow.
>
> We recommend starting with Process Builder, especially if your business process boils down to a simple if/then statement. For example:
>
> **IF** a case is escalated, **THEN** notify the owner of the associated account.
>
> Process Builder includes almost all the functionality that’s available with Workflow, and then some. In fact, a single process can do what it would normally take multiple workflow rules to do, which helps you avoid limits.
>
> There are only two things that you can do with workflow that you can’t do with processes.
>
> - Configure actions to be executed at different times.
>   With a process, you can configure actions to be performed later, but all those actions are performed at the same time. If you need multiple “later”s, use workflow. For example, use multiple time triggers in a workflow rule to send an account manager email reminders one month, two weeks, one week, and three days before the related contract expires.
> - Send outbound messages without code. However, you can work around this limitation by calling Apex code from a process.
>
> If the process is too complicated for the Process Builder or requires more advanced functionality, create a flow with Visual Workflow. For example, create a flow if you need to:
>
> - Use complex branching logic (that is, if certain conditions are true, evaluate for further conditions)
>   Example: First, check whether a case is escalated. Second, check the account’s region and route the case accordingly.
> - Sort through, iterate over, and operate on several records
>   Example: After an opportunity is closed and won, calculate the opportunity’s discount. Then apply that discount to all the related opportunity products.

There is also a module specifically for how to **[Automate Basic Business Processes with Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/business_process_automation/process_builder).**